# when importing a directory how a select a certain folder in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code I have written is, when you input 5 different directory do 5 different loops. But what T want to do is insert a single directory, which has 5 different folders and implement a single loop.

Here is the code I have written now:

```
def find_threshold(dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4, dir5):
    #Finding mean for Buisness
    business_mean = 0
    business_sum = 0
    n = 0
    index = 0
    business_mean_list = []

    for path, _, files in os.walk(dir1):
        for file_name in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

            print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

            filename_1 = filepath

            for path, _, files in os.walk(dir1):
                for file_name in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

                    #print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

                    filename_2 = filepath

                    # Program to measure the similarity between 
                    # two sentences using cosine similarity.
                    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

                    # X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
                    # Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
                    #filename_1 = "buisness1.txt"
                    #filename_2 = "world1.txt"
                    A = open(filename_1, encoding='utf-8')
                    B = open(filename_2, encoding='utf-8')

                    X = A.read()
                    Y = B.read()

                    # tokenization
                    X_list = word_tokenize(X) 
                    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

                    # sw contains the list of stopwords
                    sw = stopwords.words('english') 
                    l1 =[];l2 =[]

                    # remove stop words from the string
                    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
                    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

                    # form a set containing keywords of both strings 
                    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
                    for w in rvector:
                        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
                        else: l1.append(0)
                        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
                        else: l2.append(0)
                    c = 0

                    # cosine formula 
                    for i in range(len(rvector)):
                            c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
                    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
                    n += 1
                    if cosine != 0: 
                        #print("similarity: ", cosine)
                        #mean += np.mean(cosine)
                        business_sum += cosine
                        #print("sum: ", business)
                        #print("n: ", n)
                    #else:
                        #print("similarity is zero")

            business_mean = business_sum/n
            #print(index)
            business_mean_list.insert(index, business_mean)
            index += 1
            #print("business_mean: ", business_mean)
            #print("business mean list: ", mean_list)
    business_threshold = min(business_mean_list)
    
    #Finding mean for Entertainment
    entertainment_mean = 0
    entertainment_sum = 0
    n = 0
    index = 0
    entertainment_mean_list = []

    for path, _, files in os.walk(dir2):
        for file_name in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

            print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

            filename_1 = filepath

            for path, _, files in os.walk(dir2):
                for file_name in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

                    #print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

                    filename_2 = filepath

                    # Program to measure the similarity between 
                    # two sentences using cosine similarity.
                    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

                    # X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
                    # Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
                    #filename_1 = "buisness1.txt"
                    #filename_2 = "world1.txt"
                    A = open(filename_1, encoding='utf-8')
                    B = open(filename_2, encoding='utf-8')

                    X = A.read()
                    Y = B.read()

                    # tokenization
                    X_list = word_tokenize(X) 
                    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

                    # sw contains the list of stopwords
                    sw = stopwords.words('english') 
                    l1 =[];l2 =[]

                    # remove stop words from the string
                    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
                    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

                    # form a set containing keywords of both strings 
                    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
                    for w in rvector:
                        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
                        else: l1.append(0)
                        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
                        else: l2.append(0)
                    c = 0

                    # cosine formula 
                    for i in range(len(rvector)):
                            c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
                    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
                    n += 1
                    if cosine != 0: 
                        #print("similarity: ", cosine)
                        #mean += np.mean(cosine)
                        entertainment_sum += cosine
                        #print("sum: ", entertainment_sum)
                        #print("n: ", n)
                    #else:
                        #print("similarity is zero")

            entertainment_mean = entertainment_sum/n
            #print(index)
            entertainment_mean_list.insert(index, entertainment_mean)
            index += 1
            #print("entertainment_mean: ", entertainment_mean)
            #print("entertainment mean list: ", mean_list)
    entertainment_threshold = min(entertainment_mean_list)
    
    #Finding mean for local
    local_mean = 0
    local_sum = 0
    n = 0
    index = 0
    local_mean_list = []

    for path, _, files in os.walk(dir3):
        for file_name in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

            print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

            filename_1 = filepath


            for path, _, files in os.walk(dir3):
                for file_name in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

                    #print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

                    filename_1 = filepath

                    # Program to measure the similarity between 
                    # two sentences using cosine similarity.
                    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

                    # X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
                    # Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
                    #filename_1 = "buisness1.txt"
                    filename_2 = "world1.txt"
                    A = open(filename_1, encoding='utf-8')
                    B = open(filename_2, encoding='utf-8')

                    X = A.read()
                    Y = B.read()

                    # tokenization
                    X_list = word_tokenize(X) 
                    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

                    # sw contains the list of stopwords
                    sw = stopwords.words('english') 
                    l1 =[];l2 =[]

                    # remove stop words from the string
                    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
                    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

                    # form a set containing keywords of both strings 
                    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
                    for w in rvector:
                        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
                        else: l1.append(0)
                        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
                        else: l2.append(0)
                    c = 0

                    # cosine formula 
                    for i in range(len(rvector)):
                            c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
                    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
                    n += 1
                    if cosine != 0: 
                        #print("similarity: ", cosine)
                        #mean += np.mean(cosine)
                        local_sum += cosine
                        #print("sum: ", local_sum)
                        #print("n: ", n)
                    #else:
                        #print("similarity is zero")
            local_mean = local_sum/n
            #print(index)
            local_mean_list.insert(index, local_mean)
            index += 1
            #print("local_mean: ", local_mean)
            #print("local mean mean list: ", mean_list)
    local_threshold = min(local_mean_list)
    
    #Finding mean for sports
    sports_mean = 0
    sports_sum = 0
    n = 0
    index = 0
    sports_mean_list = []

    for path, _, files in os.walk(dir4):
        for file_name in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

            print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

            filename_1 = filepath


            for path, _, files in os.walk(dir4):
                for file_name in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

                    #print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

                    filename_1 = filepath

                    # Program to measure the similarity between 
                    # two sentences using cosine similarity.
                    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

                    # X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
                    # Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
                    #filename_1 = "buisness1.txt"
                    filename_2 = "world1.txt"
                    A = open(filename_1, encoding='utf-8')
                    B = open(filename_2, encoding='utf-8')

                    X = A.read()
                    Y = B.read()

                    # tokenization
                    X_list = word_tokenize(X) 
                    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

                    # sw contains the list of stopwords
                    sw = stopwords.words('english') 
                    l1 =[];l2 =[]

                    # remove stop words from the string
                    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
                    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

                    # form a set containing keywords of both strings 
                    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
                    for w in rvector:
                        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
                        else: l1.append(0)
                        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
                        else: l2.append(0)
                    c = 0

                    # cosine formula 
                    for i in range(len(rvector)):
                            c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
                    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
                    n += 1
                    if cosine != 0: 
                        #print("similarity: ", cosine)
                        #mean += np.mean(cosine)
                        sports_sum += cosine
                        #print("sum: ", sports_sum)
                        #print("n: ", n)
                    #else:
                        #print("similarity is zero")
            sports_mean = sports_sum/n
            #print(index)
            sports_mean_list.insert(index, sports_mean)
            index += 1
            #print("sports mean: ", sports_mean)
            #print("sports mean list: ", mean_list)
    sports_threshold = min(sports_mean_list)

    #Finding mean for world
    world_mean = 0
    world_sum = 0
    n = 0
    index = 0
    world_mean_list = []

    for path, _, files in os.walk(dir5):
        for file_name in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

            print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

            filename_1 = filepath

            for path, _, files in os.walk(dir5):
                for file_name in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

                    #print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

                    filename_1 = filepath

                    # Program to measure the similarity between 
                    # two sentences using cosine similarity.
                    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

                    # X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
                    # Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
                    #filename_1 = "buisness1.txt"
                    filename_2 = "world1.txt"
                    A = open(filename_1, encoding='utf-8')
                    B = open(filename_2, encoding='utf-8')

                    X = A.read()
                    Y = B.read()

                    # tokenization
                    X_list = word_tokenize(X) 
                    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

                    # sw contains the list of stopwords
                    sw = stopwords.words('english') 
                    l1 =[];l2 =[]

                    # remove stop words from the string
                    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
                    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

                    # form a set containing keywords of both strings 
                    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
                    for w in rvector:
                        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
                        else: l1.append(0)
                        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
                        else: l2.append(0)
                    c = 0

                    # cosine formula 
                    for i in range(len(rvector)):
                            c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
                    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
                    n += 1
                    if cosine != 0: 
                        #print("similarity: ", cosine)
                        #mean += np.mean(cosine)
                        world_sum += cosine
                        #print("sum: ", world_sum)
                        #print("n: ", n)
                    #else:
                        #print("similarity is zero")
            world_mean = world_sum/n
            #print(index)
            world_mean_list.insert(index, world_mean)
            index += 1
            #print("world mean: ", world_mean)
            #print("world mean list: ", mean_list)
    world_threshold = min(world_mean_list)
    
    return (business_threshold, entertainment_threshold, local_threshold, sports_threshold, world_threshold)
```

As you can see I'm inputing 5 directories to the method `find_threshold` and doing a cosine calculation for 5 directories in 5 loops which at the end gives out 5 values as outputs of each loops. What I want to do is give 1 directory (it have 5 folders with 100 text files each) for the method `find_threshold` and get the same output.

Such like,

```
def find_threshold(dir):
```

Can anyone help me to write the code for this?

Comment: ```
def your_function(dir_list):
    ans = []
    for dirname in dir_list: 
        required_output = your_cosine_function(dirname)
        ans.append(required_output)
        
    return tuple(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take any of your sections and make find_threshold() just do one directory at a time. Then when the user specifies a parent folder you can search it for direct children and call find_threshold() on each of them.

Maybe something like this I totally have not tested:

```
def find_threshold_by_parent(parent_directory):
    return [find_threshold(dir) for dir in os.listdir(parent_directory) if os.path.isdir(dir)]

def find_threshold(child_directory):
    #Finding mean for Buisness
    mean = 0
    sum = 0
    n = 0
    index = 0
    mean_list = []

    for path, _, files in os.walk(child_directory):
        for file_name in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

            print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

            filename_1 = filepath

            for path, _, files in os.walk(child_directory):
                for file_name in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)

                    #print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")

                    filename_2 = filepath

                    # Program to measure the similarity between
                    # two sentences using cosine similarity.
                    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

                    # X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
                    # Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
                    #filename_1 = "buisness1.txt"
                    #filename_2 = "world1.txt"
                    A = open(filename_1, encoding='utf-8')
                    B = open(filename_2, encoding='utf-8')

                    X = A.read()
                    Y = B.read()

                    # tokenization
                    X_list = word_tokenize(X)
                    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

                    # sw contains the list of stopwords
                    sw = stopwords.words('english')
                    l1 =[];l2 =[]

                    # remove stop words from the string
                    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw}
                    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

                    # form a set containing keywords of both strings
                    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set)
                    for w in rvector:
                        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
                        else: l1.append(0)
                        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
                        else: l2.append(0)
                    c = 0

                    # cosine formula
                    for i in range(len(rvector)):
                            c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
                    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
                    n += 1
                    if cosine != 0:
                        #print("similarity: ", cosine)
                        #mean += np.mean(cosine)
                        sum += cosine
                        #print("sum: ", sum)
                        #print("n: ", n)
                    #else:
                        #print("similarity is zero")

            mean = sum/n
            #print(index)
            mean_list.insert(index, mean)
            index += 1
            #print("mean: ", mean)
            #print("mean list: ", list)
    threshold = min(mean_list)

    return threshold
```